# How use multiple IP on VPS server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on VPS server. I buy 2 extra IP addresses and I have problem to use them. I try configure

> /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

file and I think do that properly because on

> sudo netplan --debug apply

I don't see any errors, but... when I try

> ping www.google.com

I get message:

> ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Generally I want have possibly to rotate IP adresses. Anyone have idea how do that properly?

---

@davidgo

**Ifconfig** file  contains strange characters, something like Egyptian hieroglyphs.

**Resolv.conf** file is (exclude comments lines):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search openstacklocal
```

I read about resolv.conf earlier and when I edited that file I can connect with www.google.com, but this file sometimes overwrites itself (i think by session).

**50-cloud-init.yaml** file contains (default):

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
            set-name: ens3
```

I try edit this file like this (IPv4 version):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: 
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      match:
        name: eth0
      addresses: [54.38.50.208/32]
      gateway4: 54.38.50.1
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      match:
        name: eth1
      addresses: [51.75.50.116/32]
      gateway4: 51.75.50.1
```

and like this (IPv6 version):

```
network:
     version: 2
     ethernets:
         eth0:
             dhcp6: false
             match:
               name: eth0
             addresses:
               - "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:334b:3274/128"
             gateway6: "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:334b:32fe"
```

Both alternatives versions are correctly, but result was the same. Ifconfig return my basic IP address and I don't know how connect with website from other IP.

Ultimately, I thought about VPN, but when I use VPN then Putty/WinSCP break the connection and I have to restart server from client panel.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of understanding of the basics. A temproary failure in name resolution relates to DNS. You really need to flesh out what you intend by rotate IP addresses dependong on whether its server or client and the purpose the answer will be very different. Also, are al your IPs in the same subnet?

Comment: You are totally right, I'm newbie at network's so I need help. I calculate ip's on paper, they isn't on the same subnet. I add  that my subnet mask is = 255.255.255.255.

Comment: What is the output of /sbin/ifconfig;  cat /etc/resolv.conf and what does 50-cloud-init.yaml contain?  Also, do you need to use netplan?